# xml to richtextbox, do some formatting in the RTB, perhaps change data, then save RTB text back to xml

Tags: xml, richtextbox

I am writing a screenwriting application for myself.
I save the data (sceneheaders, dialogue etc...) to xml.
I can load the xml data into a RichTextBox alright, but I don't want it to show any tags.  If I wanted to just replace the tags with nothing I could use

```
    Dim Pattern = "<.*?>"
    Dim myString = Regex.Replace(str, Pattern, "")
    rtbScript.Text = myString
```

if the xml reads :

```
<Cue>Nadine</Cue>
```

then after running the code the RTB shows Nadine. And this it will do with all the nodes, as expected.  But the tag is gone, and so is the link to the node.
If I wanted to change the character's name from let's say Nadine to Jennifer in the RTB, it can not be saved to the same node in xml, because there is no more tag.

So basically, I need the tag to still 'be there', so that if I change the text in the RTB it can be saved to the xml as

```
<Cue>Jennifer</Cue>
```

How can this be done?  Is it even possible to keep the tag in the RTB, but invisible, untouchable?

Comment: There's no provision in a RichTextBox to make part of the text non-editable while other parts can be edited. It's a text editor. You can parse the XML to put into the RTB (keeping the original XML) and then write it back when you're done editing. This would require that you not insert or delete actual lines in the RTB content, but you could edit individual lines. Or better yet, you could use a more appropriate tool for the task than a RTB, like a TreeView or ListView.

Comment: @Ken White : That is what I was afraid of.  I wonder how the commercial applications do it.  Thank you for your reply!